# Entity Framework 6.0 - Strange behaviour on delete

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework-6

I decided to use for the first time Entity Framework 6.0. So yes I'm new to this.
As always, I have created the database first and then I produce the Code First model (through Visual Studio wizard) which looks like this:

```
Partial Public Class DataContext
Inherits DbContext

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("name=DataContext")
End Sub

Shared Sub New()
    DbInterception.Add(New FullTextInterceptor())
End Sub

Public Overridable Property StatusInfoes As DbSet(Of StatusInfo)
Public Overridable Property UpdateSets As DbSet(Of UpdateSet)
Public Overridable Property Users As DbSet(Of User)

Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ByVal modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(New UpdateSetFtsMap)

    modelBuilder.Entity(Of StatusInfo)() _
        .Property(Function(e) e.Information) _
        .IsUnicode(False)

    modelBuilder.Entity(Of UpdateSet)() _
        .Property(Function(e) e.Title) _
        .IsUnicode(False)

    modelBuilder.Entity(Of UpdateSet)() _
        .Property(Function(e) e.Files) _
        .IsUnicode(False)

    modelBuilder.Entity(Of UpdateSet)() _
        .HasMany(Function(e) e.StatusInfoes) _
        .WithRequired(Function(e) e.UpdateSet) _
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(False)

    modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
        .Property(Function(e) e.Login) _
        .IsUnicode(False)

    modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
        .Property(Function(e) e.Password) _
        .IsUnicode(False)

    modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
        .Property(Function(e) e.Surname) _
        .IsUnicode(False)

    modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
        .Property(Function(e) e.Name) _
        .IsUnicode(False)

    modelBuilder.Entity(Of User)() _
        .HasMany(Function(e) e.StatusInfoes) _
        .WithRequired(Function(e) e.User) _
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
End Sub

Public Function GetServerDate() As DateTime
    Return Database.SqlQuery(Of DateTime)("Select GetDate()").SingleOrDefault
End Function

End Class
```

So I have an **UpdateSet** object with at least one **StatusInfo** object.
So far so good.

The strange thing is the delete. Here is my code:

```
Public Function DeleteById(id As Integer) As Integer Implements IDataMapper(Of UpdateSetDataTransferObject).DeleteById
    Dim result = -1

    Using ctx As New DataContext
        Dim dbUpdateSet = (From o In ctx.UpdateSets Where o.Id = id Select o).SingleOrDefault

        If dbUpdateSet IsNot Nothing Then
            ctx.UpdateSets.Remove(dbUpdateSet)

            Try
                ctx.SaveChanges()
                result = 0
            Catch ex As DbUpdateException
            End Try
        End If
    End Using

    Return result
End Function
```

The strange thing is that sometimes it works. (1 out of 20 let's say).
By debugging I observed that in most cases the code

```
ctx.UpdateSets.Remove(dbUpdateSet)
```

removes all StatusInfo objects (child objects) from the StatusInfoes collection so I suppose that EF has no information about children to delete. So I get the error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_UpdateSetStatus_UpdateSet". The conflict occurred in database "UpdateWizard", table "dbo.StatusInfo", column 'UpdateSetId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

As I have mention earlier, there are some times that it works. Those times the collection of StatusInfo objects was not cleared by the remove command.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting this error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_UpdateSetStatus_UpdateSet". The conflict occurred in database "UpdateWizard", table "dbo.StatusInfo", column 'UpdateSetId'.

which in my opinion is not EF error it error coming from the sql server regarding a fact that you have a foreign key constraints which means you canot delete the record because other record depend on it.

Comment: @shadow You have to delete all StatusInfo entries with the given UpdateSetId before you delete the UpdateSet.

Comment: Thank you both for your time. I know it is from SQL Server but I don't understand why in some cases works fine and in other does not.    @dckuehn I thought that this is a job for EF. I don't want to believe that we have to do this for every parent-child relation. For me the problem occurs in the ctx.UpdateSets.Remove(dbUpdateSet) statement.Somehow there is the point that information is lost.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be more helpful.  The company I work at doesn't believe in hard-deleting any data, we set `Deleted=True` booleans wherever we need to, so I'm not familiar with deleting data, though I do use EF a lot.  Search for "Cascading Delete", it may get you closer to what you need.

Comment: Do you have access to database when you get error,  run that SQL code against DATABASE  and if it show the error directly on sql, show it to your company

Comment: @coldTold: It is a local project (mine project) at home. Just trying EF 6.0  My guess is that something is missing in Fluent API code. I find it strange that when I remove a parent object from its dBSet, the remove command clears the children collection. After that it is logical to get an error because there is no information for EF to first delete children and then parent row. It attempts to delete only the parent which is not allowed by a constraint in database. Still searching. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and now it seems obvious. I just had to enable cascade delete on the foreign key constraint between the parent (UpdateSet object) and the children (StatusInfo object). Reading an article about modifying entities in EF4.0 I fell on a paragraph that says "Turn cascade delete on or off both in database and EF configuration". In my case, because database was created first, this was off, so when I created the model (code first) it was also off in EF. So I guess that in this case I had to delete all children by hand. To be honest, because I'm old school, I'm not really excited with this (cascade delete on constraint) but I can't imagine other way for EF to do it. So thank you all once more. Hope this helps others.